# Не открывает страницу во фрейме

Tags: html

Доброго времени суток!
Есть такая проблема: нужно сделать *.html страницу на который во весь ее размер будет отображен фрейм с содержанием этого продукта.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>XXXXXXXX</title>
 </head>
 <frameset cols="100%">
      <frame src=http://(LocalHost):3011/ name="CONTENT">
 </frameset>
</html>
```

Проблема:
Хром возвращает пустую страницу. IE предлагает перейти на содержание странице во фрейме, в новой вкладке.

Как сделать что бы не было такой беды? Чтобы страница открывалась во фрейме без переходов.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: @DominicSagona, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Comment: А адрес фрейма, что, прямо такой и указан — "http://(LocalHost):3011/"? Если да, то убиранием скобок проблема решится.

Если нет, то проверяй content-type этого документа "http://localhost:3011/".

Comment: нет это я тут написал таким образом.(там все написано норм.

Answer (score 1):

Пробуй [так](http://codepen.io/discipleartem/pen/ZYgLQo?editors=100). Правишь только scrolling="yes" на "no", если не нужен скролл

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>XXXXXXXX</title>
 </head>
 <frameset>
      <frame src="http://htmlbook.ru/html/frameset" name="CONTENT" scrolling="yes" noresize>
 </frameset>
</html>
```